# Could anyone please say, assign activists problem for rpa

Tags: rpa

I found this error when solving uipath problem.Coukd anyone please help to solve this problem
[image: I found this error when solving uipath problem.Coukd anyone please help to solve this problem]

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a data in your collection/array/DataTable that doesn't exist, that is not in the range of your collection (if you have 2 rows in your DataTable,  you can't access row 4)

Looks like a basic thing, but feel free to share with us a little bit more if you're stuck, details of your assign activity for example.